# Visual Studio Publish, The “PublishTelemetry” Task Could Not Be Loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, msbuild

I am not able to publish to azure my web api, after updated Visual studio 2015 update 3.
The error message says:

> The “PublishTelemetry” task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll.
>   Confirm that the declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the fix [here](http://jondjones.com/visual-studio-publish-the-publishtelemetry-task-could-not-be-loaded/). I edited with admin rights, the file

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets

and removed the tag `PublishTelemetry` and its using tag. After edition, I restarted visual studio. Now I am able to deploy again.

Comment: I had to wait 2 days until doing that. now it is marked. thanks

Comment: Remember to remove the tag (element) and the task. Would love to know what this is for, for later, when something else doesn't work. Possibly its Azure and/or ApplicationInsights.

Comment: This happened to us.  Brought down all our CI builds.

Answer (score 5):

Even after editing the admin rights it wasn't working so I just install the **MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets** from **NuGet**.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets package from NuGet and replaced the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web folder with MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web folder from tha package.